# Unwanted characters when email opened in outlook

Tags: email, outlook, email-client

This is very weird and am not able to find any source of information on the internet.

There is an application (in asp.net if that matters) with me which creates and sends emails.

These emails are seen correctly on email clients like gmail and Windows Live mail.

Only in case of MS Outlook the exact same mail (saved from Windows Live mail and opened in Outlook) is showing some undesirable characters.

Of course on generating from the application also shows the characters (and not just by saving it).
The following is the comparison screenshot [image: here].

At least some direction as to where should I look will be of great help!

Cheers,

Comment: Could "user agent" create problems? The user agent I am using is "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"

Comment: In Outlook, Word renders HTML messages, not IE. Please show the relevant snippets of your HTML.